# Haskell multiple arguments function

Tags: haskell

```
myfunc:: [Int] -> Int -> Int   
myfunc mylist i =
    if length(mylist) == 0 then 1

    else
       (head(mylist) * i) +  myfunc((tail(mylist)) (i+1))
```

I want to get a weighted sum over a list.

for example, at given parameter `[10,9,8,7,6]` and `1`,
I want to get `10*1 + 9*2 + 8*3 + 7*4 + 6*5 ..`

But my code puts error that

```
test.hs:9:18: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘Int -> Int’
```

how to fix this problem??

Comment: there are to many *parentheses*: `myfunc((tail(mylist)) (i+1))` - try `myfunc (tail mylist) (i+1)` (you call `tail (mylist)` with `(i+1)`)

Comment: Function calls in Haskell don't require brackets. `function first_argument` is enough. Multiple arguments are passed like `function first_argument second_argument third_argument`, which is the same as `((function first_argument) second_argument) third_argument`. A function with type `a -> b -> c` is actually a function with type `a -> (b -> c)`: it takes one argument (like all Haskell functions), and returns another function.

Comment: You seem to program in Haskell like you would do in an *imperative* programming language. Mind Haskell is a *functional* programming language. Therefore you should program *functionally*. Your current code is very *un*-Haskell.

Comment: There's nothing imperative about this code; it just uses `head` and `tail` instead of pattern matching. The same function could be written `myfunc [] i = 1; myfunc (x:xs) i = x*i + myfunc xs (i + 1)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should check your parentheses - you use much more of them then you need to (leading to the problem here)

If you look at `myfunc((tail(mylist)) (i+1))` then if you count the `(..)` you will see that the one argument to `myfunc` here is `tail(mylist) (i+1)` but this would mean that you try to apply `(i+1)` to `tail(mylist)`

Also instead of the check with `length` and `head` you can use pattern-matching.

here is a cleaned up version of your function:

```
myfunc :: [Int] -> Int -> Int   
myfunc [] _ = 1
myfunc (h:tl) i = h*i + myfunc tl (i+1)
```

which will return `111` for your example:

```
> myfunc [10,9,8,7,6] 1
111
```

---

I don't know how much you've seen of Haskell but you can express this as

```
myfunc :: [Int] -> Int -> Int   
myfunc weights start = 1 + sum (zipWith (*) weights [start..])
```

too - which I would consider more readable and idiomatic

**Also:** - why the `1` if the list is empty? Shouldn't your weighted *sum* be `0` if the list is empty??

Comment: Thank you for answering. That code is just prototype of my assignment. I rewrite my code recommended style, but 1 problem occurred. what I have to do execute function at specific situation? for example,  myfunc (h:tl)  = if check h++tl == True then somthing. how this style code would be rewrited? I want to erase "if then" statement.

Comment: first `h++tl` is probably not what you want (it's `h:tl`) - and this depends on what `check` is really doing (does it really need the remaining lists or only the `h`?) - please open another question where you describe your real problem / this problem